# Кто нибудь пользовался SAM-IT/abac для yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

кто нибудь пользовался [SAM-IT/abac](https://github.com/SAM-IT/abac) для yii2, не могли бы привести пару примеров использования?

Или этим [PHP-Casbin](https://github.com/php-casbin/php-casbin)?

Comment: Моё мнение таково: если на **это** нет документации и не приведены примеры, то лучше этим и не пользоваться

Comment: Чаще всего все задачи решаются RBAC'ом, ABAC не сильно распространён и более сложен в настройке - поэтому очень мало примеров в сети.